# React - googlebot won't receive all static files

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, digital-ocean, googlebot

I have a React website hosted in Digital Ocean. Everything works when I open my website. But when I view the page as Google in the Search console, Page resources section, I see an error that 3-4 of them (I have 26 total css/js files) cannot be loaded. When I run test again, I see the same result - some files couldn't be loaded. Error is "Other error". But each time those files are different. First I am able to download style.css, but cannot main.css the other time vise versa, etc. What's wrong? Is the problem in Google Bot or in my hosting configuration? Thanks.